# Python API/webscraping exercise with JSON

Tags: python, json, python-responses

I am learning python and am working on API/webscraping.  I have an exercise which seems to be giving me difficulty on the first steps.  Ultimately, I am supposed to write a function that gets the number of  jobs from a json list of jobs that contain specific key values in a field.  But to start with, I'm just trying to pull any sort of json data.

the content of the resource should look like [this](https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/Accessing%20Data%20Using%20APIs/jobs.json)

```
api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"
response = requests.get(api_url)
jsonResponse = response.json()
print(jsonResponse)
```

produces

```
None
```

I have also tried:

```
session = requests.Session()
api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"
response = session.get(api_url)
jsonResponse = response.json()
print(jsonResponse)
```

but that also produces

```
None
```

I can confirm that the content type is json:

```
h = requests.head('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data')
header = h.headers
contentType = header.get('content-type')
print(contentType)
```

produces

```
application/json
```

But I'm not sure what to make of the 'Content-Length' and 'Connection' attributes from:

```
h = requests.head('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data')
header = h.headers
print(header)
```

which produces:

```
{'Server': 'Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.9.2', 'Date': 'Thu, 05 Jan 2023 17:25:29 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '5', 'Connection': 'close'}
```

I've also tried limiting the results by passing the 'Id':'225' as a params in the get request but that didn't change anything. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I just can't seem to figure it out.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
After debugging the "hosting" notebook, I was able to get it to run error free.  During this debugging, I noticed the relevant sections which should help in identifying what the resource is expecting.

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def api_id():
    # Check if keys such as Job Title,KeySkills, Role Category and others  are provided as part of the URL.
    #  Assign the keys to the corresponding variables..
    # If no key is provided, display an error in the browser.
    res = None
    for req in request.args:
        
        if req == 'Job Title':
            key = 'Job Title'
        elif req == 'Job Experience Required' :
            key='Job Experience Required'
        elif req == 'Key Skills' :
            key='Key Skills'
            
        elif req == 'Role Category' :
            key='Role Category'
        elif req == 'Location' :
            key='Location'
        
        elif req == 'Functional Area' :
            key='Functional Area'
        
        elif req == 'Industry' :
            key='Industry'
        elif req == 'Role' :
            key='Role'
        elif req=="id":
             key="id"
        else:
            pass
    
        value = request.args[key]
        if (res==None):
            res = get_data(key,value,data)
        else:
            res = get_data(key,value,res)

    # Use the jsonify function from Flask to convert our list of
    # Python dictionaries to the JSON format.
    return jsonify(res)
```

I noticed that it is providing a 'None' response if it does not receive the proper arguments. So I tried:

```
api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"
params = {'id':'225'}
r = requests.post(api_url,data=params)
jsonResponse = r.json()
print(jsonResponse)
```

This produces a JSONDecodeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 params = {'id':'225'}
      3 r = requests.post(api_url,data=params)
----> 4 jsonResponse = r.json()
      5 print(jsonResponse)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py:900, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    894         except UnicodeDecodeError:
    895             # Wrong UTF codec detected; usually because it's not UTF-8
    896             # but some other 8-bit codec.  This is an RFC violation,
    897             # and the server didn't bother to tell us what codec *was*
    898             # used.
    899             pass
--> 900 return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

File /usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    341     s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:
    348     cls = JSONDecoder

File /usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    332 def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):
    333     """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334     containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336     """
--> 337     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338     end = _w(s, end).end()
    339     if end != len(s):

File /usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I also tried to retrieve the text but it seems that's not allowed.  I have verified it is using utf8 encoding but it seems I'm still missing something.

Comment: what do you get if you print `response.text` or `response.ok`?

Comment: Have you tried hitting that URL with a browser or `curl` just to see it the expected data is actually returned? The `Content-Length: 5` in the response headers seems to indicate not..

Comment: `response.ok` produces `True` and `response.text` produces `null`

Comment: If `response.text` is `null` that's what your server is actually returning. Fix that to be the JSON you want and your code here should work.

Comment: Well this sucks then.  The course I'm taking had a Jupyter notebook that they said to "just run" without modifying to self-host the data.  So I spun up a sandbox server, installed jupyter, and ran it.  I saw some errors but figured it was ok since it was responding on the port.  Unfortunately much of it uses flask and I don't have much experience with that.  So I guess I'll either need to debug that or take a step back and figure out a different approach.

Comment: You could just dump the JSON in a file for now, read it from there, and do the rest of the exercise. Replacing that with a load from URL will be trivial once your course runners figure out how to fix that part.

Comment: Posted update to the question.  It now seems as if I'm getting a JSONDecodeError.  I've verified it is using utf8.  I've also posted the relevant section of the "host" code in the hopes that this will provide some insight as to what it is expecting.

Comment: I've also tried
`api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"
params = {'Job Title':'Digital Media Planner'}
r = requests.post(api_url,json=params)
jsonResponse = r.json()
print(jsonResponse)`
but still get JSONDecodeError

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that was being looked for here was something like:

```
api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"
payload = {'Location':'New York'}
r = requests.get(api_url, params=payload)
```

I think there were multiple things causing issues, many, if not all, related to how this course is having us "host" the data instead of providing online and consistent/standard resources.  Thanks IBM/Coursera!

Answer (score -1):

This will do the job hopefully

```
import requests
def get_json():
    result= requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/data")
    print(result.content.decode('utf-8'))
    # use ascii if utf-8 don't give you the result
    print(result.content.decode('ascii'))
get_json()
```